# Setting up Hudson with Selenium RC to run tests written in C#

Tags: selenium, hudson, integration-testing, mbunit, test-runner

I just deployed a Hudson server and configured it to checkout, build and deploy to a testing http server.

Now I want more =)

I have some Selenium RC tests wrtten in C#/.Net, using the MbUnit infrastructure, that runs ok on Gallio Icarus.

How to setup Hudson to run these tests? Our is in a Windows 2003 server.

I was thinking about just setting a batch script that runs the tests. But how to run them in CLI? Is there a CLI test runner that could run our tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hah! Just found out.

I have to run:

```
Gallio\bin\Gallio.Echo.exe path\MyTestAssemlby.dll
```

When Google fails you, try searching your own PC =)

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer NAnt, MSBuild or PowerShell you can use those too...

Comment: Our project uses .Net 3.5 framework. Does NAnt works? How do I use MSBuild or Powershell to run our tests via console?

Comment: Yes this should all work with .Net 3.5.  Current nightly builds also work with .Net 4.0 if you were so inclined.

For use from the console, I recommend sticking with Gallio.Echo.exe unless you want to integrate Gallio into existing NAnt, MSBuild or PowerShell scripts that you have written.  In each of those cases it's just a matter of asking the host tool (NAnt, etc.) to load up the tasks or cmdlets provided by Gallio.